# Flow mapper plugin failed

Tags: qgis, plugins, flow-map

I want to create a desire line with the Flow Mapper plugin using QGIS version 2.1. After I did, it has failed. The data that I used is pictured below. There may be an error procedure I have used. Can anyone suggest how to do it right?

[image: Data]

Answer (score 3):

Please check that your data is in correct format. Decimal separator is "." point and items are tab or space delimited.

At first, it might be better to run the plugin with the test data provided under the installation folder. (or download the plugin from http://cempro.dyndns.org/FlowMapper-0.4.zip and extact the sample data)

Interaction matrix should be square. Meaning that, if you have 9 nodes, you must have 9 rows and 9 columns in the txt file storing the matrix.

Prefer ANSI encoding and watch out for any extra null lines

In the screenshot, select the flow matrix as KOORDINAT_TUJUAN2.txt not KOORDINAT_TUJUAN3.txt

Try filenames without any spaces e.g. prefer "file_name.txt" rather than "file name.txt" Also it might be good to keep the paths shorter e.g. c:\test\data...

I am the developer of this plugin. If you need any further help feel free to contact. 
You can also email me your data so I can arrange it for you and send back.
Contact info is avaliable on plugin website http://cempro.dyndns.org

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and link the tutorial. I will try, if I have problems I will confirm via email. thank you